# GetWindowTextA returns gibberish with unrelated code changes

Tags: c++, winapi

I've tried this code which was supposed to get all window titles and positions and store them in vectors (here window titles are printed) but the outputs seemed completely random:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<LPSTR> buffs;
std::vector<int> rectposs;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam)
{
    LPSTR buff;

    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
    {
        GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buff, 254);
        buffs.push_back(buff);
        RECT rect;
        if (GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect))
        {
            rectposs.push_back(rect.left);
            rectposs.push_back(rect.right);
            rectposs.push_back(rect.top);
            rectposs.push_back(rect.bottom);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    for (LPSTR buff : buffs)
    {
        std::cout << buff << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I expected the output to contain lines like `Settings` and `Alarms and Clock` since I had them open but instead everything was along the lines of `���$`, and what confused me was if I removed lines 20-23 (push back the positions of windows) the problem was apparently fixed, which shouldn't be the case since it has nothing to do with `GetWindowTextA` or how I saved the window titles. As such I wasn't able to produce a minimum reproducible example since seemingly unrelated code seemed to change the output completely.

Are my suspicions that this has something to do with lines 20-23 overwriting the window titles correct? If so or otherwise how can I make sure it doesn't happen and still have the data I want?

Comment: You never allocated your buffer before passing it to GetWindowTextA. You need to malloc() it or allocate it on the stack first. My C++ knowledge is pretty light so I'm not sure how that'll interact with the vector.

Comment: You might also want to use GetWindowTextLengthA to determine how big to make your buffer.

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buff, 254);`, what do you think the `254` indicates? Are you expecting data to be written into memory somewhere? If so, where? At this point in the program, where do you expect `buff` to be pointing, and why? Do you expect that to cause a problem? If not, why not? Did you try reading the documentation for `GetWindowTextA`? After reading the documentation, do you still see things the same way?

Comment: All compilers will warn about using uninitialized variables. Did you disable warnings? Re-enable them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `buff` variable is an **uninitialized** pointer, it doesn't point anywhere meaningful.  So your call to `GetWindowTextA()` is writing to random memory.  To fix that, you need to allocate actual memory for it to write to.

After fixing that, you have another problem - you are pushing the same pointer into the `buffs` vector on each iteration.  So, once the enumeration is finished, all entries will be pointing to the same memory, which will hold the result of the *last* call to `GetWindowTextA()`.  To fix that, you need to make a *copy* of the `buff` data on each push.  The easiest way to solve that is to change your `buffs` vector to hold `std::string` values instead of `LPSTR` pointers.

Lastly, I suggest changing the `rectposs` vector to hold actual `RECT` objects instead of the individual `int` values (though, you should consider defining a new `struct`/`class` to hold all of the window info you want, and then use a single `vector` to hold objects of that type).

Try this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>

std::vector<std::string> buffs;
std::vector<RECT> rectposs;

BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(HWND hWnd, long lParam)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(hWnd))
    {
        CHAR buff[255]{};
        GetWindowTextA(hWnd, buff, 254);
        buffs.push_back(buff);

        RECT rect;
        GetWindowRect(hWnd, &rect);
        rectposs.push_back(rect);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

int main()
{
    EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, 0);
    for (string& buff : buffs)
    {
        std::cout << buff << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: line 29: `for (std::string& buff : buffs)`, but from aside from that it works perfectly, thanks!

Comment: "line 29: for (std::string& buff : buffs)" Pardon; what exactly do you mean? If you are saying that the compiler did not accept this, that depends on the version of C++ you are using. Otherwise, I don't understand.

Comment: @celphato If you are not using C++11 or later, use this loop instead: `for (size_t i = 0; i < buffs.size(); ++i) { std::string& buff = buffs[i]; ... }`

Comment: @Karl Knechtel oh in that case my apologies, yes the compiler didn't accept that.